# How can I modify my bilinear filtering RGBA image resize function to accept an RGB input?

Tags: c++, c

I am using the following function to resize RGBA images with bilinear filtering:

```
 int a, b, c, d, x, y, index ;

    float x_diff, y_diff, blue, red, green ;
    int offset = 0;
    float x_ratio = ((float)(w1-1))/w2 ;
    float y_ratio = ((float)(h1-1))/h2 ;


    for (int i=0;i<h2;i++) {
        for (int j=0;j<w2;j++) {
            x = (int)(x_ratio * j) ;
            y = (int)(y_ratio * i) ;
            x_diff = (x_ratio * j) - x ;
            y_diff = (y_ratio * i) - y ;

            index = (y*w1+x);  


            a = input_pixels[index] ;
            b = input_pixels[index+1] ;
            c = input_pixels[index+w1] ;
            d = input_pixels[index+w1+1] ;

            // blue element
            // Yb = Ab(1-w1)(1-h1) + Bb(w1)(1-h1) + Cb(h1)(1-w1) + Db(wh)
            blue = (a&0xff)*(1-x_diff)*(1-y_diff) + (b&0xff)*(x_diff)*(1-y_diff) +
                   (c&0xff)*(y_diff)*(1-x_diff)   + (d&0xff)*(x_diff*y_diff);

            // green element
            // Yg = Ag(1-w1)(1-h1) + Bg(w1)(1-h1) + Cg(h1)(1-w1) + Dg(wh)
            green = ((a>>8)&0xff)*(1-x_diff)*(1-y_diff) + ((b>>8)&0xff)*(x_diff)*(1-y_diff) +
                    ((c>>8)&0xff)*(y_diff)*(1-x_diff)   + ((d>>8)&0xff)*(x_diff*y_diff);

            // red element
            // Yr = Ar(1-w1)(1-h1) + Br(w1)(1-h1) + Cr(h1)(1-w1) + Dr(wh)
            red = ((a>>16)&0xff)*(1-x_diff)*(1-y_diff) + ((b>>16)&0xff)*(x_diff)*(1-y_diff) +
                  ((c>>16)&0xff)*(y_diff)*(1-x_diff)   + ((d>>16)&0xff)*(x_diff*y_diff);

            output_pixels[offset++] = 
                    ((((int)red)<<16)&0xff0000) |
                    ((((int)green)<<8)&0xff00) |
                    ((int)blue) |
                    0xff000000;
        }
    }
```

This works fine but I would like to be able to input an RGB image, and output a fully resized and filtered RGBA image in order to avoid having to do the entire conversion first.

My understanding of bitshift operations is minimal at best, therefore, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Something like `unsigned int get_rgb(const void *data, unsigned index) { const uint8_t *rgb = (const uint8_t *)data + 3 * index; return (rgb[0] << 16) | (rgb[1] << 8) | (rgb[2]); }`. Then call that to get the values for the `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` pixels.

Comment: @IanAbbott - Thanks... That got to where I needed to be, although I had to change the ordering or the returned pixels for my purposes.  Brilliant, thank you.  If you write up your comment I will mark it answered.

Comment: Since you are using 8 bit rgb pixel values they are likely modified by a gamma (look up sRGB) . Keep in mind that when resizing it's a good idea to convert them first to linear space. After resizing, you can convert them back.